# Blender 2.8 Add-ons "Testing" content missing

Tags: export, add-on

I am trying to activate the Plug-in "Export Camera to After Effects JSX". I have researched that it is under the tab Preferences > Add-ons tab "Testing". However, there is no content here with Blender 2.8. I am working on Mac. I have also tried a colleague's Mac and my PC and the content is always missing.
How does one activate the content?

Comment: Have you installed the add-on? Add-ons from the [*Blender Add-ons Contrib*](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/) repository aren't included/pre-installed in the official releases. The add-on can be found [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/io_export_after_effects.py).

Comment: Perfect. This worked. Many thanks.